# How to make a shortcut to a object in a class in java

Tags: java

I was wondering is there a way to make  a shortcut to a object in another class in java like say I have a String and I want to access it in another class in java without needing to say the class name period then the strings name

```
    //Like this
    //This is the first class
    String Hello = "Testing";
    //Here is the second class
    System.out.println(FirstClass.Hello);
```

I don't want to have to type in FirstClass.Hello I want to type in just Hello how could I make a shortcut like that (If there is a way.)

Comment: what? please show some code of what you are trying to access / achieve.

Comment: I have changed the post how is that?

Comment: If that it is a static field in first class then you can add a static import for that in the second class.

Comment: try programming when not drunk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two solutions, depending on the situation.

#### Static Import.

If the member you want to access is static, you can import it statically. For example, if you want to access `System.out` with just `out`, you can do this:

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
```

#### Assign the value to a local variable

If you don't need to assign new values to the member you want to access, you can assign the member to a local variable

```
int myValue = Some.value.you.want.to.access;
```

Now instead of writing `Some.value.you.want.to.access`, you can just write `myValue`.

Comment: @ComputerCoderAN If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark! Also, remember not to overuse static imports. They might cause name conflicts and reduce readability.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to access an Object in a Class without creating its object in that class.

You can achieve that by doing a **static import** of the Class/Interface where object exists. Refer the below example:

Interface with the objects of which you wish to create shortcuts:

```
public interface Constants {
   Object OBJ = new Object();
   String STR = "XYZ";
}
```

Do a static import of the above interface to use the object shortcuts:

```
import static Constants.*;

public class UserClass {
   public static void main(String... args){
     System.out.println(OBJ.getClass());
     System.out.println(STR);
   }
}
```

Hope this helps.